# how to add price in cart from dropdown

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, cart

**I want to add price when click one of them**

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
                            <select class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                              <option value="0">Not Required</option>
                              <option value="50">Before Care only(6am to 9am)</option>
                              <option value="60">After Care Only (5pm to 7pm)</option>
                              <option value="110">Both</option>
                              </select>
                          </div>
```

It should be added their in cart total

```
 <h4 class="price" id="prictot">{{$cdetail ->c_price}}</h4>

         <form action="{{ route('/payment') }}" id="theForm" method="POST">
          @csrf
          <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="{{$cdetail ->price}}"><br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn radius-xl text-uppercase">Buy This Courses</button>
         </form>
```

**Using ajax and getting value and put in "prictot"**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#priceadd").on('change', function () {
    var optionText = $("#priceadd option:selected").val();
     realprice=document.getElementById("prictot").innerHTML
    document.getElementById("prictot").innerHTML = optionText 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: The price which already there inside `<h4>` let it be 10 then  if user select `Before Care only(6am to 9am)` then this will total to  i.e : 10 +50 = 60 but if user again change select to `After Care Only (5pm to 7pm)` then again the price will be taken from `h4` (60) and add total to it or the previous total (10) should be taken and add new select price to it ?

Comment: please add your answer ,i'll confusing me sir

Comment: i'm getting values like this but don't know why don't it make sum of them ..<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#priceadd").on('change', function () {
  var optionPrice = parseInt($("#priceadd option:selected").val())
 var courseprice =document.getElementById("prictot").innerHTML
 alert("Selected Option Text: "+optionPrice);
 alert("Selected Option Text: "+courseprice);
 document.getElementById("prictot").innerHTML = optionPrice + courseprice
 //document.getElementById("prictot").innerHTML = Tot
    
    //alert($(this).val());
});
});
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get value of `select-box` and `<h4>` and add them and put total value to your div and hidden inputs . i.e :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//on change of slect
  $("#priceadd").on('change', function() {
  //get select value
    var optionText = parseInt($(this).val());
    //get text inside h4
    var realprice = parseInt($("#prictot").text());
    //add 
    var total =optionText +  realprice;
    //add total to div nd inputs
    $("#prictot").text(total)
    $("#price").val(total)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
  <select class="form-control" id="priceadd">
    <option value="0">Not Required</option>
    <option value="50">Before Care only(6am to 9am)</option>
    <option value="60">After Care Only (5pm to 7pm)</option>
    <option value="110">Both</option>
  </select>
</div>
<h4 class="price" id="prictot">110</h4>

<form action="{{ route('/payment') }}" id="theForm" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="110"><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn radius-xl text-uppercase">Buy This Courses</button>
</form>
```

If you need to get the total which was already there inside `<h4>` before the value of it get change you can add a custom attribute to `<h4>` tag which will have the previous value . i.e :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//on change of slect
  $("#priceadd").on('change', function() {
    //get old value
    var old_value = parseInt($("#prictot").attr('total-price'))
  //get select value
    var optionText = parseInt($(this).val());
    
    //add 
    var total =optionText +  old_value;
    //add total to div nd inputs
    $("#prictot").text(total)
    $("#price").val(total)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
  <select class="form-control" id="priceadd">
    <option value="0">Not Required</option>
    <option value="50">Before Care only(6am to 9am)</option>
    <option value="60">After Care Only (5pm to 7pm)</option>
    <option value="110">Both</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!--added custom attribute-->
<h4 class="price" total-price="110" id="prictot">110</h4>

<form action="{{ route('/payment') }}" id="theForm" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="110"><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn radius-xl text-uppercase">Buy This Courses</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <h4 class="price" total-price="110" id="prictot">110</h4> it is came from last page with item like this <h4 class="price" id="prictot">{{$cdetail ->c_price}}</h4> .. so now when i added dropdown into this it make sum again and again whenever i click dropdown

Comment: so what do you want ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: in dropdown there is 3 options so user can select one of them and price should be added in total.,only one option price from dropdown can be added in total and one time only

Comment: So you need to disable select box ? after user select any value from it ?

Comment: means if user select one item from dropdown only that price will be added in total and after that he want to choose other then the old one will not stay added in total .new price will add everytime user change or select..

Comment: mam the only problem is it loss the value from <h4 class="price" id="prictot">{{$cdetail ->c_price}}</h4> ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218090/discussion-between-swati-and-sandy).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no need to use a hidden input for the price you get from laravel. You can insert that value directly in the js code from your blade template. See solution below.

```js
$("#priceadd").on('change', function () {
    let price = 100 // this is only for stackoverflow
    // in your project you do
    // let price = {{$cdetail->price}}
    let optionPrice = parseInt($("#priceadd option:selected").val())
    document.getElementById("prictot").innerHTML = optionPrice + price
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 class="price" id="prictot">Nothing selected</h4>
<select class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="priceadd">
  <option value="0">Not Required</option>
  <option value="50">Before Care only(6am to 9am)</option>
  <option value="60">After Care Only (5pm to 7pm)</option>
  <option value="110">Both</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how can i add  this dropdown price into total price..here " <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="{{$cdetail ->price}}">" and to show price here" <h4 class="price" id="prictot">{{$cdetail ->c_price}}</h4>"

Comment: see update, I don't think you need the hidden input at all. in your project you use the last comment line: let price = {{$cdetail->price}}

Comment: there is already fix price in <h4> which came with last page ,not when click on dropdown price shold be add in that <h4> .means if user select first dropdown price should 110(<h4>)+60(dropdown)

Comment: document.getElementById("prictot").innerHTML = optionPrice + price it just show price as it is ..like 60(dropvalue) and 100(realprice(h4))

Comment: Thats why, in your blade template, you put the same value in price variable as in h4. With this:   let price = {{$cdetail ->c_price}}